# Android: Creating a Login/Register Screen using an SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication

I want to add a Login/Register Activity at the start of my Application.

Can I do so using SQLite, I.e. with the help of a "DatabaseHelper" class?

I have already implemented a Database within my application using the DatabaseHelper class shown below that `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

Can I just create another class like this, or extend the current one? If so, how would I do so?

Current class (note this is database for storing game scores etc):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

    // Database Name
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MeditationDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_SESSION = "sessionid";
    private static final String COL_GAMETITLE = "game";
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_MED = "avgmeditation";
    private static final String COL_MAX = "maxmeditation";
    private static final String COL_AVGATT = "avgattention";
    private static final String COL_MAXATT = "maxattention";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //VERY IMPORTANT: ALWAYS CHECK THAT THERE ARE SPACES AND COMMAS IN CORRECT PLACE IN CODE BELOW:

        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "(" + COL_SESSION
                + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " + COL_GAMETITLE + " STRING, "  + COL_NAME + " STRING, " + COL_MED + " INTEGER, "
                 + COL_MAX + " INTEGER, " + COL_AVGATT + " INTEGER, " + COL_MAXATT + " INTEGER, "  + COL_SCORE +  " INTEGER, " + COL_DATE + " STRING " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);

    }

    /**
     * Method that upgrades the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * All CRUD operations
     */
    // Adding new score details (Name, score, date)
    void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // ContentValues- holds the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_SESSION, score.getSessionID());
        values.put(COL_GAMETITLE, score.getGameTitle());
        values.put(COL_NAME, score.getName());
        values.put(COL_MED, score.getMeditation());
        values.put(COL_MAX, score.getMax());
        values.put(COL_AVGATT, score.getAvgAttention());
        values.put(COL_MAXATT, score.getMaxAttention());
        values.put(COL_SCORE, score.getScore());
        values.put(COL_DATE, score.getDate());

        // Inserting Row (i.e. the values that were entered from above
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

}
```

Comment: SQLite databases are local to the device they are on. Storing login credentials on it makes little sense.

Comment: OK so what are the alternatives? using MySQL and a server?

Comment: If you don't have anyone to work on a back end for you, you could look into using the AndEngine cloud

Comment: Thanks, what exactly is that?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach here is to inner class your helper. Then add method to your outer class to manipulate the data or whatever else like login or register!

```
public class DataAccsses {

    public Boolean login(String username, String password){

    }
    public Boolean regester(//what ever needed here){

    }

    //other data manipulation method from your helper


    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //keep everything private. outer class can access inner class private members. 
    }
}
```

You only need one helper in your application (except rare conditions) So do not create another one. You can put as many as methods in your outer class DataAccess as needed to cover all the oprations on the database on all the tables.